# Apache forward proxy with SSL is not using HTTPS?

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, https

I've configured a forward proxy in Apache 2.4, but my requests through it result in a 400:

> curl: (56) Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT

```sh
# Using the proxy results in a 400
https_proxy=https://my.example.net:3443/ curl 'https://testapi1.millimanintelliscript.com/Irix/IASRequestWS.asmx?WSDL'
# Skipping the proxy but running the command from my.example.net results in a 200
curl 'https://testapi1.millimanintelliscript.com/Irix/IASRequestWS.asmx?WSDL'
```

I wonder if the proxy is not using SSL because when I use `curl -v`, the output includes the following line, which mentions `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS`:

```
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to testapi1.millimanintelliscript.com:443
```

**What could the problem be?** This is my proxy config at `my.example.net`:

```
Listen 3443

<VirtualHost *:3443>
    ServerName my.example.net

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyRequests on
    ProxyVia off

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.example.net/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.example.net/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.example.net/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```